# Spring websocket - stompJS, Is it possible to send messages with callback function without subscribing?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have the following code from a very popular spring websocket demo:

```
   stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/greeting', function(greeting) {          
        displayQueueMessage(greeting);
    });

function sendName() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  stompClient.send("/app/wsdemo", {}, JSON.stringify({
    'name' : name
   }));
}
```

On connect, we actually subscribe to to a queue and provide a callback method.

Now, imagine i have a server service for the websocket that is called **getAllUsers**

and lets assume i have 2 different components in my front end, **usersOnGeographicMap**,  **usersOnDataTable**.

lets assume this 2 view components want to make use of the server service (getAllUsers). 
these 2 component each has a callback function, (one that displays the users on a geographic map, the other callback function draws them on a data table)

the problem now is that i only subscribe to a queue once, and provide him with one callback function. so how do i solve this issue?

ofcourse in ajax it will be very easy because each call is provided with a call back:
   -usersOnGeographicMap.getUsersAjax(callback1)
   -usersOnDataTable.getUsersAjax(callback2)